# Setting up ADFS for Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs

I'm in the process of setting up IFD for CRM, and can't get past the internal login part of the claims based setup. I can browse both the adfs and crm metadata. When I try to browse to the internal crm url (https://internalcrm3.XXX.com:447/crm2013) I get prompted for credentials to adfs ("Enter username and password for htts://adfs3.xxx.com"). The url has changed to the adfs url (https://adfs3.xxx.com/adfs/ls/wia?....) at this point upon the login failure. There are no errors in the adfs event long, not sure where to check for this failure. The crm site worked prior to me setting up claims based authentication. I'm using windows 2012r2, I'm running crm on port 447. 
Fiddler shows a 200 from internalcrm3, and a 200 for adfs3 (it shows adfs3 is on 443, but I haven't set up anything in IIS for this, as it's the 2012r2 version of adfs)
If I browse https://adfs3..com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon, I am prompted and can login wit the same credentials I'm trying above.

Comment: Have you installed SP1 for CRM 2013? (and preferably ur1 for sp1)

Comment: Not sure if you are still running into this problem, but I'd guess that it may have to do with the port number for your internal CRM URL since it isn't the default SSL port number.  I'd go through the whitepaper, "Configuring Claims-based Authentication for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server" available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41701 for the steps on configuring as well as some troubleshooting guidelines.  I've found it to be quite helpful for setting up ADFS with the amount of detail in the document and step by step instructions.